# JavaScript date runs script between 7 pm and 3 am next day

Tags: javascript, date, if-statement, time

I've got a little problem. I coding a chrome extension right now and I dont know how to handle with data. I mean that. I would like to run my script automaticly Between e.g. Today 7 pm and Tomorrow 3 am. how should i create my if to do that?

Below u can see my days declaration.

```
 today = {
            day: today.getUTCDate(),
            hours: today.getUTCHours()
        };

        var tomorrow = new Date();
        tomorrow = {
            day: tomorrow.getUTCDate() + 1,
            hours: 3
        };
```

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms

Comment: Ok i got the idea but how should i implement it? script will refresh every 10-15 mins every day between 7pm and 3 am(next day) how should i do that?

Comment: Get a Date, if `date.getHour()` is greater than 19 or less than 3, run the script. Use UTC only if you want to ignore the local time zone.